# What is causing the "Invalid Character in Identifier" error when compiling my Apex code

Tags: apex, custom-object

I've got the Following code:

```
Global class EmailToLeadTST implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
  global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, 
                                                       Messaging.InboundEnvelope env){
    // Create an InboundEmailResult object for returning the result of the  
    // Apex Email Service 
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
    String myPlainText= '';

    // Add the email plain text into the local variable  
    myPlainText = email.plainTextBody;

    // Check for existing Parent_Opportunity__C with this email address   
    Parent_Opportunity__C[] Parent_Opportunity__c = [SELECT Id, Name, Email__C
      FROM Parent_Opportunity__C
      WHERE Email__C = :email.fromAddress];

    if (Parent_Opportunity__C.size() == 0) {
      // New Parent_Opportunity__C object to be created - set LastName and Company to
      // dummy values for simplicity
      Parent_Opportunity__C newParent_Opportunity__c = new Parent_Opportunity__C(Email__C = email.fromAddress, 
        LastName__C = 'From Email', 

      // Insert a new Parent_Opportunity__C
      Insert newParent_Opportunity__C;    

      System.debug('New Parent_Opportunity__C record: ' + newParent_Opportunity__C );   
    } else {
      System.debug('Incoming email duplicates existing Parent_Opportunity__C record(s): ' + Parent_Opportunity__C );    
    }

    // Set the result to true. No need to send an email back to the user      
    // with an error message   
    result.success = true;

    // Return the result for the Apex Email Service 
    return result;
  }
}
```

and I'm getting the following Errors

Line 24 - Unexpected Token 'Insert".

Line 13 - Invalid Character in Identifier: Parent_Opportunity__c

Line 20 - Invalid Character In Identifier: NewParent_Opportunity__C

What is causing this as the code was working when I was using a salesforce object and it worked with no errors so I changes the Object to a custom one and now it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors in your Apex code.

Firstly, the **Invalid Character in Identifier** errors:

> Line 13 - Invalid Character in Identifier: Parent_Opportunity__c

This is coming from this line:

```
Parent_Opportunity__C[] Parent_Opportunity__c = [SELECT Id, Name, Email__C
  FROM Parent_Opportunity__C
  WHERE Email__C = :email.fromAddress];
```

Note that `Parent_Opportunity__c` is the API name for your custom object. You can't have the identifier in Apex also use the same name.

It would be like calling your pet dog "Dog". Yes, you can probably do it in real life and it will lead to some ambiguity. Apex avoids that problem by preventing you from doing it.

Try changing the identifier to something like this:

```
Parent_Opportunity__C[] parentOpportunityFromEmail = [SELECT Id, Name, Email__C
  FROM Parent_Opportunity__C
  WHERE Email__C = :email.fromAddress];
```

The same problem exists for your usage of `NewParent_Opportunity__c`.

---

The second syntax problem is the **Unexpected Token 'Insert"**

The is coming from:

```
Parent_Opportunity__C newParent_Opportunity__c = new Parent_Opportunity__C(Email__C = email.fromAddress, 
    LastName__C = 'From Email', 

  // Insert a new Parent_Opportunity__C
  Insert newParent_Opportunity__C;
```

The first line isn't terminated correctly, so Apex is trying to parse them as a single instruction. Change the comma on the first line to a closing bracket and semicolon. E.g.

```
Parent_Opportunity__C newParent_Opportunity = new Parent_Opportunity__C(Email__C = email.fromAddress, 
    LastName__C = 'From Email');

  // Insert a new Parent_Opportunity__C
  Insert newParent_Opportunity;
```

Comment: I did what you said and changed the identifier to ParentOpportunity and that cleared all my other errors. however, I'm still getting the Unexpected token 'Insert'. Error.

Comment: Okay I did what you said about that and now it's saying that 'newparentopportunity__C' Variable does not exist?

Comment: @KoryKent you need to replace all your usages of the `newparentopportunity__C` variable with `newParent_Opportunity`.

Comment: I think I may have something else wrong with it as it's not creating the Custom Object. If I have rules in place for fields that have to be populated would those have to be filled in?

Comment: @KoryKent If there are other required fields on `Parent_Opportunity__c` then, yes, you would need to populate those before attempting the insert operation. I'd suggest getting the Apex debug log that gets created when the InboundEmailHandler fires. Or, better yet, create Apex test methods that execute this code and assert that the expected outcomes are occurring.

Answer (score 0):

In Apex, the double underscore can only appear if you're referencing a namespace (e.g. `MyNamespace__MyObject__c`) or as part of an object's type, a custom field, or a few other things.

`Parent_Opportunity__C[] Parent_Opportunity__c` is incorrect because the name of your variable includes a double underscore. `Parent_Opportunity__c[] parentOppsList` would be better (and most importantly, syntactically valid).

The error about "Unexpected token" is because you haven't closed some parenthesis (and you're also using double underscores where you shouldn't be using them again).

Incorrect

```
Parent_Opportunity__C newParent_Opportunity__c = new Parent_Opportunity__C(Email__C = email.fromAddress, 
    LastName__C = 'From Email', 

  // Insert a new Parent_Opportunity__C
  Insert newParent_Opportunity__C;
```

Correct

```
Parent_Opportunity__C newParent = new Parent_Opportunity__c(
    Email__c = email.fromAddress, 
    LastName__c = 'From Email'
); // This is the bit you're missing. Closing the parenthesis to indicate that you're done with the constructor

// Insert a new Parent_Opportunity__C
Insert newParent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have a couple errors in your syntax.

You cannot declare an array with a custom object api name. 
(I believe you cannott use the double underscore in names)

You need to use another name:

```
Parent_Opportunity__C[] liParentOpp = [SELECT Id, Name, Email__C
      FROM Parent_Opportunity__C
      WHERE Email__C = :email.fromAddress];
```

this is also the case for :

```
Parent_Opportunity__C newParent_Opportunity__c
```

You should declare it using a proper name:

```
Parent_Opportunity__c parentOpp = new Parent_Opportunity__c
```

Also, you need to finish your statement below by adding a closing bracket and a semi-colon)

```
Parent_Opportunity__C newParent_Opportunity__c = new Parent_Opportunity__C(Email__C = email.fromAddress, 
        LastName__C = 'From Email');
```

Personally, it would be easier to read / catch syntax errors if you wrote it like this:

```
Parent_Opportunity__c parentOpp = new Parent_Opportunity__c(
     email__c = email.fromAddress;
     LastName__c = 'From Email'
);

insert parentOpp;
```

try that and see if it works, otherwise you need to further debug your code